# IBM IHS Reverse Proxy Configuration

Tags: http, https, reverse-proxy, ibmhttpserver

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy using IBM HTTP server and what I want to do is that user will hit a HTTP url to my reverse proxy server that will forward request internally to HTTPs server.

HTTP Address <--> Reverse Proxy (IBM HTTP Server) <--> HTTPS server (https://example.com)

In my configuration I have enabled mod_proxy & mod_proxy_http and configured below ProxyPass

```
Proxypass / https://example.com
```

But I am unable to configure it. I am getting error:

```
proxy: HTTPS: failed to enable SSL support for example.com
```

Anybody help what I might be doing wrong. I have also already loaded below modules:

```
LoadModule ibm_ssl_module modules/mod_ibm_ssl.so
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a `KeyFile` and `SSLProxyEngine ON`.

Caveat:

However, generally IBM HTTP Server uses the WebSphere WebServer Plug-in as a websphere-specific HTTP reverse proxy plugin that doesn't share any of this configuration.

Most people use IBM HTTP Server because it's supported by IBM, but it's only supported by IBM when you use it in a way prescribed by a product that bundled it. That's rarely w/ mod_proxy.

Comment: Hi Covener, what ssl certificate Keyfile shall point to? As I am setting up it as a HTTP server connecting to another HTTPS based server.

Comment: You need a keyfile that trusts the issuers of the certificates used on your   backend